# Did anybody receive a Google Map APIKey for IOS?

Tags: api-key, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have applied for APIKey of google map for IOS several times at this site: https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access, but they did not reply at all.
I even don't know why I did not receive the APIKey.

Does anybody have met this problem and figured it out?
Or any suggestions?
Thanks very much!

Comment: same problem here, unable to get api key.

Comment: Same here. There is same closed question in SO with much negative rating and they said you should complain to Google rather than ask a question on SO.

Comment: This is not really a question for here. I know developers with keys